# How to match between positive and negative integer

Tags: c++

I want to add a RegExp in QLineEdit to have the possibility to enter positive and negative integer separate by 1 or n whitespace.

So i try

```
QString name_rx = "[0-9]+\\s+[0-9]+";
QRegExp rx;
rx.setPattern(name_rx);
QValidator* validator = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this); 
ui.LE_ObjectName->setValidator(validator);
```

I expect the output of the algorithm to be for example :

15 -987   144745 4 -98 11 2    125

Comment: you don't have `-` in your regex to handle negative numbers...

Comment: RegExp is great as a configuration options, but crappy as a part of code. They are hard to read (so hard to maintain). It is easy to write something which looks correct, but fails in some corner case and since it is hard to read it is hard to fix this mistakes. That is why I'm saying just use two `QLineEdit`s with integer validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for your input, it validates the whole line instead of each number separately. It also handles positive numbers with `+` sign.

```
QString name_rx = R"re(^(\+?\-?\d*\s?)*$)re";
```

I tested it on https://regex101.com/ using the below string if that might help.

```
15 -987 144745 4 -98 11 2 125
-98 -3242 +123
+15 -23
10                                 -20100
```

Comment: Doesn't work. i think it's for JS code not work with QRegExp

Comment: Seems like `[[:space:]]` is not recognized by every flavor of regex. I've edited the answer, try it again please.

Comment: Use C++11 raw string literals to avoid problems with backslash, which you have and that is why it doesn't work for OP.

Comment: i can't enter anything in myLineEdit. i think you regExp block any input data @SilvanoCerza

Comment: @MarekR is right, thanks for the edit. Try again with the new edit please.